# how to plan a trajectory in cartesian space using OMPL

Tags: ros, ompl, cartesian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!Guys!
I use OMPL to plan a trajectory in Moveit! But it seems that OMPL just plan in joint space as default.
I wonder can OMPL plan a trajectory in cartesian space in Moveit.
I will be grateful if any of you could help!
Thank you !
Yours sincerely!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230112/how-to-plan-a-trajectory-in-cartesian-space-using-ompl/) by [gutianqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26191/gutianqi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a MoveIt! tutorial that talks about Cartesian paths [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pr2_moveit_tutorials/html/planning/scripts/doc/move_group_python_interface_tutorial.html#cartesian-paths). Have you tried it? Here is the relevant part:

> You can plan a cartesian path directly by specifying a list of waypoints for the end-effector to go through.

```
waypoints = []

# start with the current pose
waypoints.append(group.get_current_pose().pose)

# first orient gripper and move forward (+x)
wpose = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()
wpose.orientation.w = 1.0
wpose.position.x = waypoints[0].position.x + 0.1
wpose.position.y = waypoints[0].position.y
wpose.position.z = waypoints[0].position.z
waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

# second move down
wpose.position.z -= 0.10
waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))

# third move to the side
wpose.position.y += 0.05
waypoints.append(copy.deepcopy(wpose))
```

> We want the cartesian path to be interpolated at a resolution of 1 cm which is why we will specify 0.01 as the eef_step in cartesian translation. We will specify the jump threshold as 0.0, effectively disabling it.

```
(plan3, fraction) = group.compute_cartesian_path(
                         waypoints,   # waypoints to follow
                         0.01,        # eef_step
                         0.0)         # jump_threshold

print "============ Waiting while RVIZ displays plan3..."
rospy.sleep(5)
```

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2016-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gutianqi](https://answers.ros.org/users/26191/gutianqi/) on 2016-03-27**:
I wonder if it can plan a Cartesian path in visual editor RVIZ using ompl. Just use the "plan and execute"  button and some other configuration it can plan a Cartesian path visually in RVIZ. Thank you!

**Comment by [Qt_Yeung](https://answers.ros.org/users/13976/qt_yeung/) on 2016-08-02**:
I interpolate straight line with compute_cartesian_path(), but the calculated joint accelerations are very big even if I modify the jump_threshold value, do you know how to improve it?

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-08-04**:
I'm not sure, you might want to open a new question.